# Great user interface UI examples? Screenshots

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for examples of really great Android user interfaces. Really, all across the board are of interest.

My own app has a bunch of different ListViews. Looking for inspiration for themeing the background, the border, the listviewitem background, font, etc..

Comment: check http://www.android-app-patterns.com//category/grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into http://androidniceties.tumblr.com/ In my opinion, the best UI designs are there. Good for inspiration.